# Folder tree in Finder sidebar (or stuck to Finder)

Tags: finder, plugins, simbl

Is there a Finder plugin (maybe [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) plugin) which allows one to see the directory structure in the Finder's sidebar (instead of Favorites, Shared, Devices) or in an attached window?

Something like this:

[image: Finder somehow with sidebar]

There is Cover Flow, but it's not what I need.

Also I don't need any Finder replacement; I just want to fix this missing feature in Finder.

Comment: I think you're going to end up with a Finder replacement :)

Comment: Consider hiding finder sidebar and using column or list view until you get it sorted.

Comment: "missing" is relative, it's just not there. Otherwise check out http://www.cocoatech.com/pathfinder/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there's a SIMBL plugin to do that. What you're asking for would be a fairly extensive rewrite even if you had the source code for the Finder.

Your best bets are what @jtbandes and @Richard's comments on your question state: get a Finder replacement that does that or use list view in the Finder.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a program called [Owlfiles](https://apps.apple.com/gr/app/owlfiles-file-manager/id510282524) for MacOS that is the closest I've found to what you're wanting. I find the lack of a navigation pane in Finder irritating... Honestly Apple, just copy Microsoft's File Explorer already as it is far more superior for advanced file management tasks.